# How to refresh a uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to refresh my `UITableView` after hitting a button.  When I hit the button it does add a new cell but it does not add the things like labels in the cell.  I believe it may have to do with my piece of code that doesn't let the labels get jumbled up when scrolling around.  Here is my view controller data code.

P.S. I am using `[tableview reloadData]` in my button code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    [self ref];
    [self getNumOfRows];
    return numRows-2;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    }
    else{
        UIView* subview;
        while ((subview = [[[cell contentView] subviews] lastObject]) != nil)
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }


    int idNum = 1;

    /*NSString *getStrResult;

    NSString *getURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/MyPhpStuff/stuff/sendData.php?id=%@&db=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",idNum],@"ConversationTest"];

    NSData *getDataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getURL]];

    getStrResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:getDataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];*/
    [self ref];
    idNum++;
    UILabel *textLabel;
    UILabel *userLabel;
    if(![username isEqualToString:[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(159/255.0) green:(4/255.0) blue:(223/255.0) alpha:1];
    }

    if([username isEqualToString:[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(176/255.0) green:(247/255.0) blue:(146/255.0) alpha:1];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.font = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 18.0];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 25)];
    textLabel.text = [text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];

    userLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 25)];
    userLabel.text = [users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:userLabel];    

    idNum++;
    return cell;
}
```

Here is my code for the button:

```
- (IBAction)post:(id)sender{
    NSString *post = postText.text;
    NSString *post2 = [post stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/MyPhpStuff/stuff/post.php?username=%@&text=%@&db=%@", username, post2, @"ConversationTest"];

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self ref];
    [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that `[tableview reloadData]` doesn't work?

Comment: It kind of works because it is reloading and getting that there is a new cell that needs to be made so it creates a new cell but it is not populating the cell with the two labels that it should.

Comment: Instead `[cell.contentView addSubview:userLabel];` use `[cell addSubview:userLabel];`

Comment: @Azat... you never add subviews to the cell directly. Always add subviews to the content view

Comment: ok I will give that a try

Comment: @TheCodingArt OP's code already contains `addSubview:` calls, just to test what is going wrong. It is so bad formatted that it is hard to read it and suggest something more...

Comment: @Azat, understood and agreed lol. Honestly, I think he should start going to raywenderlich.com to learn how to use the iOS SDK. This functionality is practically the basics of basics and if there's difficulty, it usually indicates lack of understanding to how the SDK works (in this case to how tableViews work)

Comment: @Azat The [cell addSubview:userLabel]; did not work for me.  It made the labels all jumbled up looking.

Comment: @Azat Would it be that I have to have refrence the table and use that to do [self.tableview reload].  Everywhere I check people are using [self.tableView reload]

Comment: But you already said that you are using reloadData method call and that it is not working well. This is a well known method to refresh all table. And it should work

Comment: @Azat ok I figured out it is working but for some reason the [self ref]; isn't working when I call reloadData which is weird because it works when I use [self ref] on load

Comment: I don't see the code for ref, what is it doing?

Comment: @Azat It is calling 2 methods one gets the users from a table in a data base and adds it to a array and the other gets the text from the table in the database and adds it to a array.

Comment: It shouldn't work when you call reload data. Just call it manually. There's no reason not to work

Comment: @Azat why shouldn't it work?

Comment: @Max sorry it's typo, it should work

Comment: @Azat add a answer so I can choose u because u helped my problem.

Comment: @Max I added an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several well known methods for refresh the `UITableView`.

1. `-reloadData` - this method totally refreshes the whole table view, by keeping the current row position on the screen. However, this works not very beautiful and there are two other methods
2. `-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` - you can call that method with one of `UITableViewRowAnimation` enum type to animate reloading a table view. You also specify here which sections you wish to reload
3. `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` - it is similar to previous method except here you pass `indexPath`s array of cells which you wish to reload

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a custom [UITableViewCell (tutorial)](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

You can add the subviews to your custom cell and set their values inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Then you won't need to do this: "`[subview removeFromSuperview];`"

---

After creating an implementation using your code and some test data I was able to tap a button, add an object to mutable arrays `text` and `users`, call `[self.tableView reloadData]`, and see the data appear in the table. My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is identical to yours.

Be sure to check that you're getting the data you expect via `objectAtIndex:`.

Answer (score 0):

You should structure/build your cell content only when you create the cell, not when you dequeue it (if  the structure of the dequeued cell is the same, but that is the purpose of it).

Refactor your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

        textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 300, 25)];
        textLabel.tag = 100001; // a big integer to identify it

        [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];

        userLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 25)];
        userLabel.tag = 100002; // another big integer
        [cell.contentView addSubview:userLabel];    
    }
    else 
    {
        // retrieve subviews
        textLabel  = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100001];
        userLabel  = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100002];
    }

    // what is the need for this local variable?   
    int idNum = 1;

    /*NSString *getStrResult;

    NSString *getURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/MyPhpStuff/stuff/sendData.php?id=%@&db=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",idNum],@"ConversationTest"];

    NSData *getDataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getURL]];

    getStrResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:getDataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];*/

    // what is this call doing?
    [self ref];

    idNum++;

    if(![username isEqualToString:[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(159/255.0) green:(4/255.0) blue:(223/255.0) alpha:1];
    }

    if([username isEqualToString:[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(176/255.0) green:(247/255.0) blue:(146/255.0) alpha:1];
    }

    textLabel.text = [text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];

    userLabel.text = [users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:userLabel];    

    // again, what is the need for this?
    idNum++;

    return cell;
}
```

The `tag` that you can assign to a UIView is to be able to retrieve later by a call to `viewWithTag:`. Be aware that small values are already used by the system (like in UITableViewCell internal hierarchy).